# ¿Cómo puedo agregar valores de una lista en una url?

Tags: python

Mi pregunta es sencilla, ¿cómo puedo agregar valores de una lista dentro de una palabra?, y que por cada vez que imprime un valor se le agregue una coma y si llega al final no la agregue.

Ejemplo:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                      
   list = ['palabra1','palabra2','palabra3']                                               
   print("palabras: %s", for i in : %(x))
```

Comment: ¿Me pones un ejemplo de cómo quieres que quede la salida del método?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que quieres, ¿imprimir "`palabra1,palabra2,palabra3"`?

Comment: @FJSevilla Si tal cual.

Comment: @XBoss, Deseo que imprima algo asi "palabras: palabra1,palabra2,palabra3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes el código:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    list1 = ['palabra1','palabra2','palabra3']
    res = ",".join(list1)
    print("palabras: " +res)
```

Te recomiendo no utilizar palabras reservadas para definir el nombre de las variables, aquí te dejo una lista de las palabras reservadas: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/palabras-reservadas-del-lenguaje/

Answer (score 0):

Si solo es imprimir la lista de cadenas separadas por una coma, usa el argumento `sep` de la función  [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) que intercala una cadena entre cada objeto a imprimir (por defecto es una cadena vacía) y desempaqueta la lista:

```
lista = ['palabra1','palabra2','palabra3']
print(*lista, sep=",")
```

Puedes combinarlo con dos dos llamadas a `print` para obtener la salida que deseas:

```
lista = ["palabra1", "palabra2", "palabra3"]
print("Palabras: ", end="")
print(*lista, sep=", ")
```

O puedes usar `str.join` si quieres crear una nueva cadena o vas a imprimir en un intérprete interactivo como muestran las otras respuestas:

```
print("Palabras: ", ", ".join(lista))
```

Por cierto, no uses `list` como nombre de una variable, está enmascarando el built-in `list`, aunque no es una palabra reservada y no cause una excepción directamente porque no se haga uso del built-in en ese código, como mínimo es confuso. En todo caso usa `list_` como marcan las convenciones.

Comment: No conocía eso, gracias!